# Firebase Error : the data keep duplicate it self instade of update the child values

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

the data keep duplicating instade of updating the data , before flutter 3 was working fine without any problems,
my code

```
 var dailydata = database_Reference
    .child("users")
    .child(SharedPref.userUid!)
    .child("dayliRecords")
    .child(date);

  dailydata.set({
  "name": SharedPref.user_id,
  "router_bssid": thisWifiObject!.bssId,
  "date": dailyWorkTime,
  "startingTime": startingTime,
  "endingTime": endingTime,
  "totalWorkTime": SharedPref.hours == 0 ? 0 : SharedPref.hours,
  "percent": SharedPref.percent == 0 ? 0.0 : SharedPref.percent,
  "connectedfrom": thisWifiObject!.macAddress,
});
```

and in the firebase :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an artifact in the Firebase console, which shows the `set` operation as removing the old value of that node (in red) and then adding the new value (in green).

If that is indeed what is happening, the UI should show the correct final state after the animations are done. And on the API level this should not affect the behavior at all, and it should fire a `child_changed` event for the `dayliRecords` [sic] node..

Comment: the problem is that , i update the value every 2 secendes and in my builder i got streambuilder to get the data , so when the data in firebase get deleted and readding it again my application view look like it blinking how can i solve it

Comment: As said, the way the console shows the data has no effect on how the API exposes it. Please edit your question to [show how anyone of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your application view.